# PHP cURL's TCP_FASTOPEN option is not available

Tags: ubuntu, php, tcp, curl

According to [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), the PHP cURL option `CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN` is available since cURL version 7.49.0 and PHP version 7.0.7.

According to what phpinfo reports on my server, i'm running PHP 7.3.7 and cURL 7.65.3 and yet when i try to use TFO with PHP cURL, it reports the following runtime error:

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN - assumed 
'CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) 

Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be int, string given
```

Which is exactly the same error that i got before i upgraded PHP and cURL to the proper versions.
Also, `php -v` also reports PHP 7.3.7 and `curl --version` reports version 7.65.3.

Comment: What is the exact question you are asking? If you could clarify what exactly you want to know, it would be helpful. 

Looking at the error messages, I also see that parameters are expected to be int, but string was provided. If you could also edit your post to include the command you are running, it would likely help identifying the exact issue.